# Quemar etiqueta [rutas-dinamicas]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Actualmente hay unas 6 preguntas etiquetadas [rutas-dinamicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rutas-dinamicas).

En mi opinión, esta es una meta-etiqueta, según está definido en el [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Sobra decir que no hay un wiki de etiqueta que oriente sobre su uso y que, en mi opinión, la etiqueta no hace ningún sentido y no ha quien pueda considerarse experto en ella.

De acuerdo a experiencias previas, si esta pregunta recibe 8 votos positivos *al hilo*, yo mismo eliminaré las preguntas para que la etiqueta desaparezca. Si recibe votos negativos, pero alcanza una diferencia de +10, haré lo mismo.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!!!!!

Comment: Seria una meta-etiqueta esto: compilar, procesamiento-de-texto o busqueda? Por las preguntas: ¿Compilar que? ¿Procesar en que? ¿Buscar que o en que?

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, no es que pueda hacerse la pregunta ¿xxx qué, en qué, o cómo?. La wiki de la etiqueta y, sobre todo, su resumen, están para responder esas preguntas, a términos que podrían tener varios usos en el español o en la informática y orientar sobre el uso de la etiqueta misma. Sin embargo, como se describe en el artículo referenciado en la pregunta, una de las razones de ser de las etiquetas es conectar a expertos con preguntas que son capaces de responder y, en general, identificar preguntas que pueden ser interesantes o relevantes para una persona.

Comment: @Juan, Compiladores es un tema que tiene expertos, tanto en compiladores de lenguajes específicos como de manera general. Revisando que existen varias etiquetas: [tag:compilar], [tag:compilador], [tag:compilación], si creo que hace falta crear algunos sinónimos y completar un buen wiki de etiqueta. Es probable que pase algo similar con los otros temas que mencionas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo mencionado en la pregunta, al alcanzar el soporte de la comunidad, he realizado yo mismo la edición de las preguntas para *quemar* la etiqueta, que debiera desaparecer automáticamente luego de unos días.